# Save Oracle stored procedure out clob parameter (to create JSON format) to a file with Informatica

Tags: oracle, output, procedure, informatica, clob

I'd like to create a JSON file of oracle table. To do so, I've created a Oracle SP:

```
 PROCEDURE P_JSON_GEN( SCHEMA_NAME_IN IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'CDM_MART', TABLE_NAME_IN IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL, P_JSON OUT CLOB) IS  

  v_schema_name varchar2(20);
  v_table_name varchar2(30);
  v_sql varchar2(32767);
  type t_json is TABLE of varchar2(1000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  table_json t_json; 
  v_json clob;
  CURSOR c_col_lst IS SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_cols WHERE OWNER = 'CDM_MART' AND table_name = (SELECT table_name FROM all_synonyms WHERE synonym_name = table_name_in AND OWNER= schema_name_in);

  BEGIN 

v_schema_name := schema_name_in; 
v_table_name := TABLE_NAME_IN;
v_sql := 'SELECT json_object(''';
v_json := '';

for n in c_col_lst
             loop
                v_sql := v_sql ||n.column_name||''' VALUE '||n.column_name||',''';
             end loop;
             v_sql := RTRIM(v_sql, ',''') || ' FORMAT JSON) as json FROM '||TABLE_NAME_IN;

             execute immediate v_sql BULK COLLECT into table_json;
             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_sql);
             for i in 1 .. table_json.count
             loop 
             v_json := v_json || table_json(i) || chr(10);
             end loop;

        P_JSON := v_sql;
        RETURN; 
    end;
```

So it creates me an output CLOB (as it is a long string) and, as I cannot save it on DB server, I need to save it on Informatica server, so I'd like to use WFL with following mapping to save the output into file on server.

[image: mapping]

WFL executes successfully, file is created, but nothing written.
When I have changed the output to varchar2(4000) in SP and string(4000) within mappings  it had created the file.

Could you please suggest how should I resolve datatype mismatch and is it possible to save such long variable into a file?

Comment: You can convert the data type in SP to text (100000 or some large number). And then in target text file you can mention same length for the column.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can save max length of string into to a file. Looking at your design, seems to be there is no any conflict on the datatype. You can use string to string mapping